# Complex serialization to string - using inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization

I am writing a C# class that serializes a specific type to a large string composed from lines.
I also want to create a "special" serializer that for some instances writes part of the lines differently. For example I want the special serializer to serialize only lines 3, 4 and 7 in a different way than the regular serializer does.

I thought of two ways I can do this with the special serializer inheriting from my serializer, but both seem to be not very elegant:

1. My serializer will be a builder. At first, I will give it the object I want to serialize, the serializer will then save a collection of lines in a protected field. When I call the build() method it will merge the collection of lines to a single string. The special serializer can override build() and manipulate the collection of lines before calling the base build().
2. My serializer will have a method for serializing each line (there can be dozens) and one method that calls all of the line serialization methods and merges their results. The special serializer will just override the methods that serialize the relevant lines.

Which way is preferred? Is there a more elegant way I didn't think of?

Comment: not really enough information to go on here.

Comment: How can I clarify this?